# ADO.NET How to read one integer value (coming along with other lists) from Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[SPName]"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "20";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "3849";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (SqlDataReader dr = db.SelectQry(cmd))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //This is select multiple rows in db so i add it to list
        }

        dr.NextResult();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
                                     //This is select multiple rows in db so i add it to list
        }

        dr.NextResult();

        //How do i read here if this statement only returns one integer value
    }
}
```

I might be able to do it with while (dr.Read()) but I don't think its right thing to do. Placing a while to read a single value.

How do I read single integer value in such situation?

Comment: Why do assign a string when it's clearly an `int`?

Comment: The while loop is indifferent if you have one or two or more records. It loops until you have data.

Comment: SelectQry is not ado.net, what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure there is single value, use if,

```
int value; //or whatever type
if (dr.Read())
{
     value = dr.GetInt32();
}

dr.NextResult();
...
```

Comment: I don't think that he's sure, that's why he has asked _"how do i read here if this statement only returns one integer value"_

Comment: And do not forget that NextResult returns boolean false if there are no results.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, even if not sure, this will return one

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan: my point was that i've understood the question as: "how to get a single value" **and** "how to check if there is no other". You've shown the answer to question 1.

Answer (score 1):

> How do i read here if this statement only returns one integer value

If you want to check if there's only one more record you can use `if(dr.Read())` twice:

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    int value = dr.GetInt32(columnIndex);
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        // should not happen, check failed
    }
}
```

Side-note: if you have a sql-parameter which type is `SqlDbType.Int` assign an `int` as value not a `string`. Don't let the database do the conversion for you, that might cause issues.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 20;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3849;
```